# log4j truncates the stacktrace

Tags: log4j, truncate

I am trying to track down a problem with GWT.  I get an error which I want to track down to the source but log4j truncates the stacktrace by indicating something like "... 26 more" hence I cannot determine the exact location for the problem.  I tried finding out if there is anyway to prevent that truncation but have been unable to find any option that will accomplish that.  Is this truncation a configurable feature?

I am running Tomcat 6.0.31, Spring 3.0 (for backend), GWT 2.1.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't log4j truncating the stack trace, it's standard Java.  And it's actually only making the trace more readable because those lines that were omitted were already output by the 'enclosing' exception.  See `Throwable` [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()).